Mocking security API in Swift
I am trying to make a Mock of the SecurityAPI calls on mac Swift. However I have big issues with creating actual class which would use those methods:
struct MacSecurityAPI: SecurityAPIProtocol {
    func SecIdentityCopyCertificate(identityRef: SecIdentity, _ certificateRef: UnsafeMutablePointer<SecCertificate?>) -> OSStatus {
        return Security.SecIdentityCopyCertificate(identityRef, certificateRef)
    }

In this code the following error is thrown:
Cannot convert value of type 'any SecIdentity' to expected argument type 'SecIdentity'

here is part of the protocol:
protocol SecurityAPIProtocol {
    func SecIdentityCopyCertificate(identityRef: SecIdentity, _ certificateRef: UnsafeMutablePointer<SecCertificate?>) -> OSStatus

I do not see any solution right now. Maybe there is a better way to mock those calls in swift? I am not very familiar with XCtest framework

It looks like you also declared your own SecIdentity protocol. Please include it in your question. In fact, you should include a [mcve].

When I will use custom SecIdentity protocol I will need to eventually pass the native SecIdentity to SecIdentityCopyCertificate and this is causing an issue. Maybe in further development i will need that, but this is not a root cause of this issue I believe

Regardless of whether this the "root cause", this is the cause of the error you have shown. SecurityAPIProtocol.SecIdentityCopyCertificate takes an instance of your own protocol, but you are trying to pass it to the Security function, which expects the SecIdentity type in Security, not your protocol.
